# Updating User-defined types in Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, user-defined-types

Is there any way to update part of a user-defined type in Oracle?

Example:

```
create or replace TYPE MY_TYPE AS OBJECT
(
    VAR_1          NUMBER,
    VAR_2          DATE,
    VAR_3          NUMBER,
    VAR_4          DATE
);
```

Sample Table:

```
create TABLE TEST_TABLE
(
    TBL_ID          NUMBER,
    MY_DATA         MY_TYPE
);
```

Is there any way to do something like the following:

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET MY_DATA.VAR_3 = 1;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but for some reason you need to alias the table:

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE T SET T.MY_DATA.VAR_3 = 1;
```