# How do you perform a PL/SQL custom object type update

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm new to PL/SQL coding and I have the following question:

I have table Foo:

```
Foo:
  foo1 number     pk
  foo2 varchar2
  foo3 varchar2
  foo4 Bar
```

bar is a custom-array object which holds attributes:

```
Bar:

bar1 varchar2

bar2 varchar2

bar3 varchar2
```

How do I write a update statement that updates the foo4?

I can't get the syntax right : /

Comment: Could you post the code that's not working so we can see it and help fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating User-defined types in Oracle 11G](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677223/updating-user-defined-types-in-oracle-11g)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the OP's other question because this is about updating a NESTED TABLE column.

Comment: can you please tell us if the answer I provided did work for your or if not why it does not? Thanks and best regards

Comment: Guilem I ended up taking a different approach to the problem. Thanks for the input though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you were trying to do it with an SQL statement and if that is possible at all, but you can do it via PL/SQL, like this (tested on Oracle 10g):

```
Declare
  v_Bar Bar;
Begin
  v_Bar := Bar
            (
              'a',
              'b',
              'c'
            );   
  --
  Update Foo
     Set foo4 = v_Bar
   Where foo1 = Id;            
  --                          
End;
```

HTH